# C++ `this` pointer

Tags: c++, c++14, this, move

1) How `this` pointer is different from other pointers? As I understand pointers point to the memory in heap. Does that mean objects are always constructed in heap, given that there is pointer to them?

2)Can we steal `this` pointer in move constructor or move assignment?

Comment: *"As I understand pointers point to the memory in heap."* It's not limited to the heap.

Comment: The first question is answered but with regards to 2, the point is you're changing address. You can't use the this pointer for your other object. Unless you just mean using this, in which case there is a best practice to do so to prevent moving to the same place: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/move-constructors-and-move-assignment-operators-cpp?view=vs-2019

Comment: @kjhf ... what?

Comment: Your understanding of pointers is wrong. A pointer may point to ANYWHERE in the memory address space.

Comment: @Swordfish I think what OP means is using the `this` keyword to refer to the moved object post move, hence steal. I'm also pointing out that the usage of `this` is a best practice in move constructors/assignment per the link to check for the same source and destination.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How this pointer is different from other pointers?

The `this` pointer only exists in the context of a non-`static` class member function. It is also implicit, it's name is a reserved keyword and it is always a [prvalue expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue). Otherwise, it's the same as any other pointer.

> As I understand pointers point to the memory in heap.

Pointers can point to anything in memory. It's not limited to the heap and neither are [objects](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object).

> Can we steal this pointer in move constructor or move assignment?

`this` is always a prvalue expression. It's not possible to assign a new address to it any more than you could assign a new value to `5`. The fact is objects exist in one place in memory for their whole life time. Their address can never change and it would be illogical to try to change that by assigning a new address to `this`. Moving from an object moves the *value* or *state* that object has elsewhere, but the object itself still exists at it's previous address.

Comment: Addition: this can never be nullptr, as calling a member function on nullptr is UB

Answer (score 7):

> How this pointer is different from other pointers?

`this` is no different from other pointers, except that you cannot change it's value and that it only exists within member functions. It is a reserved keyword.

> As I understand pointers point to the memory in heap. Does that mean objects are always constructed in heap, given that there is pointer to them?

No, pointers (valid or invalid) can point "anywhere". No, structs/classes can be allocated anywhere. On the automatic store (stack), on the free store (heap), somewhere else if the platform supports it.

> Can we steal this pointer in move constructor or move assignment?

Not exactly sure what you're asking, but the answer is most likely no.

Comment: "*No, pointers can point anywhere.*" - Nitpick. They can, though you legally cannot do much with them when they are invalid.

Comment: "but the answer is most likely no." :D

Comment: @Ayxan sowwy -.-

Comment: I don't think you can point just anywhere. You can point to `nullptr` and to existing objects and one past the existing objects. Pointing to just anywhere is probably UB in order to support platforms that trap on invalid pointers when they are formed.

Comment: @Swordfish Ooooh, those commas were important =] But now, again nitpick "*No, structs/classes can be allocated anywhere.*" is not true in the sense, that an object can have any address. Some values will never be valid pointers. Though you probably didn't mean it like that. BTW c++ standard does not have a notion of heap and stack. There is a concept called storage, it can be dynamic or static (or automatic), though implementation is not specified.

Comment: @nwp Nope, dereferencing (indirection) is UB, holding a value is fine. A pointer can have an invalid pointer value and it's fine, using it is not.

Comment: @luk32 *BTW c++ standard does not have a notion of heap and stack.* – that's why I put those terms in braces.

Comment: You can't point "anywhere" and invalid pointers don't point anywhere. But your answer is net awesome

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Standard reference?

Comment: @Swordfish Too many to cite in a comment. Can you cite the notion that pointers can point "anywhere"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit We're talking about an invalid pointer value in this case. How can you say that it doesn't point somewhere?

Comment: @Swordfish Because it doesn't? Pointers are not numbers. They're pointers. http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#basic.compound-3 http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc#4 A treasure map doesn't lead you to treasure if the treasure's gone, even though it may still have words and arrows and pictures on it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit how about wording it: A pointer can point to an object anywhere in memory. Would that be correct?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It will go down to semantics and what does it mean "to point to". I think http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3 covers it. If you say that pointer can point only to object, then yea, pointer can't point anywhere but only to objects, though it can have every value its type allows to and it will be an invalid pointer value, I guess we can skip discussing whether it points to garbage, or doesn't point anywhere, it's all clear what everyone means, I think. With the map analogy you could argue, that map still points you to a place, what's at the place is another thing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *A treasure map doesn't lead you to treasure if the treasure's gone, even though it may still have words and arrows and pictures on it.* – I'd still call it a treasure map. I know a duck when I see one.

Comment: @luk32 When my platform allows me to read dwords from 0x08000000 and I set a `std::uint32_t *foo = 0x08000000;` ... Does it point to an object in the C++ sense? I doubt that.

Comment: @eerorika Yep much better

Comment: @Swordfish Definitely not. It doesn't point to an object. It doesn't even point to an `int` (unless that `int` came to life there before). But does it point to a location in memory? Anyways, everyone understand each other here, so I guess it's fine... I mean it's a discussion about meaning of english words, and not c++ anymore. So... yea.

Comment: @Swordfish Yes but it doesn't point to treasure. Same way an invalid pointer is still a pointer but it doesn't point anywhere.

Comment: @luk32 It's understandable until you remember that source code is not a one-to-one mapping to instructions that the computer will follow. Expect your compiler/optimiser to do crazy things when you mess about with invalid pointers (irrespective of whether you dereference them)! Just code to spec and you'll be fine

Comment: Ok, let's stop that ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 'am just sayin' you can place invalid pointer values into a pointer variable, and that pointers sometimes hold such values. Nothing else, it is to the spec. I've seen production code changing behaviour based on optimization settings because of `if (this==nullptr) return 0;` ... So, I agree, expect fun stuff happen to pointer optimization, even if you can argue that you're still on the legal side.

Comment: @luk32 Can you give an example of doing that?

Answer (score 2):

> 1) How this pointer is different from other pointers?

`this` is a keyword. It cannot and doesn't need to be declared. `this` is implicitly available in non-static member functions. `this` refers to the instance argument of the member function.

Conversely, pointer variables can and generally need to be declared. An example of a pointer declaration:

```
void* ptr = nullptr;
```

> As I understand pointers point to the memory in heap.

You've misunderstood. Pointers are not limited to pointing only into heap<sup>1</sup>.

> Does that mean objects are always constructed in heap

Given that your premise is wrong, the answer remains no to this question. Objects are not limited to be constructed only in heap<sup>1</sup>. Here is an example:

```
void foo() {
    int i;
    int* iptr = &i;
}
```

The example has two objects both of which have automatic storage (i.e. not dynamic storage i.e. not heap<sup>1</sup>). One of them is an integer, and another is a pointer to the integer. Note that the pointer doesn't point to heap<sup>1</sup>.

---

> 2)Can we steal this pointer in move constructor or move assignment?

Depends on what you mean by "steal". But probably no.

---

<sup>1</sup> C++ language doesn't have a concept of "heap" memory. You probably refer to dynamic storage or free store.